# How to do svn checkout using ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Is there a way to checkout the whole directory from svn using Ansible?
Below play checks the content of that directory out, but I would also want the directory itself to be checked out.
So do I have to create the directory first and then checkout the content?

Basically my question is about checking out the content **and directory** `my-1.0.0` in `/home/ansible/temp/deploy/`.

```
 - name: Checking out the Ansible Playbook for the current Release in the Release directory
   delegate_to: localhost
   subversion:
     repo: svn://build.test/my-devops-mvp/branches/my-{{my_release_version}}
     dest: '/home/ansible/temp/deploy/'
     in_place: yes
```

I am passing the variable `my_release_version` as a command line parameter and, in SVN, under branches, I have a structure like:

- my-1.0.0
- my-1.0.2
- etc.

Comment: Have you tried it? If yes, do you get an error out of it?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε No there is no error and the above works perfectly. What i want is to export the whole directory but what is happening is checking out the contents of the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

Your fix is to actually add your desired folder in the `dest` parameter, because subversion will create the folder for you if it does not exists yet:

```
    dest: /home/ansible/temp/deploy/my-{{ my_release_version }}
```

---

The Ansible [subversion module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/subversion_module.html) actually acts exactly as the [subversion checkout command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html).

```
svn checkout URL[@REV]... [PATH]
```

In the Ansible module, what you feed in the parameter `repo` in the argument subversion is calling here `URL[@REV]...` and the parameter you feed in `dest` is what they call here `PATH`.

In that essence, you will note that the `PATH` you are checking out to when using that command, can but does not forcibly have to exist.

For example:

```
/tmp # ls -lR
.:
total 0
/tmp # svn co https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/1.0.x/notes/logo/16-colour svn-logo
A    svn-logo/subversion_logo_notxt-16m.png
A    svn-logo/subversion_logo_notxt-48m.png
A    svn-logo/subversion_logo_notxt-32m.png
Checked out revision 1877849.
/tmp # ls -lR svn-logo/
svn-logo/:
total 12
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           237 May 17 10:36 subversion_logo_notxt-16m.png
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           292 May 17 10:36 subversion_logo_notxt-32m.png
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           348 May 17 10:36 subversion_logo_notxt-48m.png
```

Also note that you can even create a full directory structure, even if it does not exists there.

```
/tmp # svn co https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/1.0.x/notes/logo/16-colour 1.0.X/notes/logo/16-colour
A    1.0.X/notes/logo/16-colour/subversion_logo_notxt-16m.png
A    1.0.X/notes/logo/16-colour/subversion_logo_notxt-48m.png
A    1.0.X/notes/logo/16-colour/subversion_logo_notxt-32m.png
Checked out revision 1877850.
```

So, as I said earlier, what hold true to the subversion commands, also holds true for the Ansible module.

Given this playbook:

```
- hosts: local
  vars:
    release: 1.0.x

  tasks:
     - name: svn co
       subversion:
         repo: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/{{ release }}/notes/logo/16-colour
         dest: /tmp/{{ release }}/notes/logo/16-colour
         in_place: yes
```

I end up with the play:

```
/ # ls -lR /tmp
/tmp:
total 0
/ # ansible-playbook play.yml -i inventory.yml 

PLAY [local] *********************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [local]

TASK [svn co] ********************************************************************************************
changed: [local]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************
local                      : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

/ # ls -lR /tmp/1.0.x/notes/logo/16-colour
/tmp/1.0.x/notes/logo/16-colour:
total 12
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           237 May 17 10:33 subversion_logo_notxt-16m.png
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           292 May 17 10:33 subversion_logo_notxt-32m.png
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           348 May 17 10:33 subversion_logo_notxt-48m.png
```